# Time series in R - Can't calculate weekly returns with different day as a reference

Tags: r, time-series, lubridate, stock

I'm learning time series in R. I can't calculate weekly returns with specified days as a closing date. The problem is in slicing but I'm able to find the solution.

The syntax is as follows:

```
library(lubridate)
TWII=read.csv("TWII.csv")
dat=as.timeSeries(TWII[,"Close"],as.Date(TWII[,1]))
bsDay=wday(dat, label = TRUE)
R1=returns(dat[bsDay=="Mon",])*100 #where the problem lies.
R2=returns(dat[bsDay=="Tue",])*100
R3=returns(dat[bsDay=="Wed",])*100
R4=returns(dat[bsDay=="Thu",])*100 
R5=returns(dat[bsDay=="Fri",])*100

>>>Error in attr(x, "tsp") <- c(1, NROW(x), 1) : cannot assign 'tsp' to zero-length vector.
```

The csv file can be downloaded here: https://github.com/ronzenith/TWII/blob/main/TWII.csv

Thanks a million.